# How can I return text from a form to a textbox C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, form-control

In my C# program, I've got a bunch of automatically generated textboxes.  On those textboxes, I add a click event that launches a form with three dropdown boxes.  After the user selects a value for each box, they click OK and the value is to be placed in the textbox.

As of right now, the click event fires just fine and the dialog comes up. After I click OK, however, the data is never put in the textbox.  Here is my click event.

```
private void clickTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(connectString + " " + unit);
            frmPickOven f = new frmPickOven(connectString, unit);
            if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Text = "";
                Console.WriteLine("Before: " + this.Text);
                this.Text = f.Oven;
                Console.WriteLine("After: " + this.Text);
            }
        }
```

The `Before:` is always blank.

The `After:` shows the new value, but the value isn't written to the textbox.

I just realized that the value is being written to the title of the form.  I thought `this` would refer to whatever called the function, but apparently not.  How can I set the value of the textbox that called the function?

Comment: Yeah, I realized that.  So how can I set the value of the textbox that called the function?

Comment: Every language has its own rules. JavaScript != C#. Learn the differences BEFORE you post here please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sender argument to the function is the control that raised the event.

```
((TextBox)sender).Text = ...
```

Comment: Thanks Vache, posted that from my phone and could not remember the code tags. Wish there was a way to up vote edits!

Answer (score 2):

`this.Text` here refers to title of the `Form` containing the `TextBox`. You should change it to

```
((TextBox) sender).Text = f.Oven;
```